# How to include Percentage symbol inside sprintf

Tags: perl

I would like to ask how can i include the symbol of percentage(%) into the output generated. 
Below is my code.

```
            $Formula = ($valueiii / $valuei) * 100 ;
            $Formula = sprintf("%04.2f", $Formula);
            $Formula = sprintf("%-12.12s", $Formula);   # File Name
            push (@data2 , " $valueiv$valuei$valueiii$Formula$valuev$valueii\t\n") ;
            $Formula = 0;


*Output generate was at the slop of Use(%)*
    DevicePart          Total       Used        Use(%)      LIMIT(%)   
     A                  50000       10161       20.32       60%        
     B                  100000      1416        1.42        80%             
     C                  125000      42258       33.81       80%             
     D                  5000        18          0.36        60%
```

i am expecting to get the 20.32% , 1.42% , 33.81% , 0.36% .
But how to included the % into each of the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

> Perl's sprintf permits the following universally-known conversions:
>
> ```
>    %%    a percent sign
> ```

Comment: Hi el.pescado, Thanks for the information. Works for me now. 
                     $Formula = sprintf("%04.2f%%", $Formula);

Comment: @cs87: Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak : Hi , how to mark "accepted" on the pages? I cant find the accepted button there.

Comment: @cs87: See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)